# Передача данных между потоками внутри класса

Tags: java, многопоточность, классы, синхронизация

Есть класс, который имеет метод добавления писем на отправку, и есть метод работающий в отдельном потоке(run), который отправляет сообщения, если они есть в очереди.Проблема в том,когда я добавляю письма в очередь внутри метода run она всегда пуст.Как мне наладить связь между потоками.

```
public class send extends Thread
{
    Queue<byte[]> arr;
    send()
    {
        arr=new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public void set(byte[] a)
    {
        arr.add(a);
    }
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if(arr.size()>0)
            {
                //Тут идет отправка сообщений
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Main(String[] eq)
{
    send va=new send();
    va.start();
    String letter="Hello world";
    va.set(letter.getBytes());        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, проблема в отсутствии синхронизации.

Без неё оптимизатор, например, имеет право считать, что раз в побочном потоке нету добавления в `arr`, то она всегда будет пустой.

Кроме того, ваш код гоняет холостой цикл в ожидании сообщения. Это неправильно, так делать не надо. Вам стоило бы воспользоваться паттерном producer/consumer (например, [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) есть примерная имплементация.)